# Delegate won't work using three view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

Is use delegate to pass data between three view controllers. I set delegate for both view controllers I want to pass data from to self inside of `MapViewController` - `MapViewController` shall receive data from both VCs.

I also added `weak var delegate: MapViewController?` to both VCs - but somehow it's only working for one of them.

MapViewController:

```
var newStartItem: MKMapItem?


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchVC = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPanel") as! SearchResultTableViewController)
        searchVC.delegate = self

        newVC = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newLocation") as! NewLocationTableViewController)
        newVC.delegate = self
        ...
        }

func addStartAnnotationToMap() {
        guard let item = newStartItem else { return }
        guard let coordinates = item.placemark.location?.coordinate else { return }

        addPin(title: item.name!, subtitle: "", coordinates: coordinates)
    }
}
```

NewLocationViewController: (this one is not working)

```
class NewLocationTableViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: MapViewController?

    ...

    func passData() {
        guard let mapItem = starts?.first else { return }
        delegate?.newStartItem = mapItem
        delegate?.addStartAnnotationToMap()
}
```

Xcode won't return any errors either!

Comment: Can you please add the code that is responsible to navigate to the NewLocationTableViewController from MapViewController? Cause if there is another object being initialised for navigation then this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare a protocol:

```
protocol MapViewControllerDelegate: class {
   func addStartAnnotationToMap()
}
```

Then change your delegate variable to:

```
weak var delegate: MapViewControllerDelegate?
```

And make `MapViewController` conform to `MapViewControllerDelegate` protocol like this:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController,  MapViewControllerDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate must be a reference from the type of your protocol

In this case: `weak var delegate: MapViewControllerDelegate?`

Answer (score 0):

For this

```
newVC = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newLocation") as! NewLocationTableViewController)
newVC.delegate = self
```

and

```
 weak var delegate: MapViewController?
```

to work you need to verify that at some point inside the map vc you present that location vc like

```
self.present(newVC,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

or push it , plus print it to verify it's not nil and guard doesn't return if `starts` is empty

```
func passData() {
    print("delegate \(delegate) item \(starts?.first)")
    guard let mapItem = starts?.first else { return }
    delegate?.newStartItem = mapItem
    delegate?.addStartAnnotationToMap()
}
```